# Is there any way to simplify ${_2F_1}(a, 1, a+2k, -1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, hypergeometric-function

Is there any way to simplify or express differently

$${_2F_1}(a,1,a+2k,-1)$$?

where ${_2F_1}$ is the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) ?

I am trying to simplify a very messy expression so any kind of different representation could be a nice first step.

Comment: What do you want? There is a Gamma representation

Comment: @JanEerland Seems great! Could you post it, together with a proof? :-)

Comment: @JanEerland I'll appreciate an answer when you have some time :-)

Comment: I was working on a proof, but the proof is very hard! I know it is equal

Comment: @JanEerland Could you post only the result in the meantime? It would be very nice ;-) The proof would be awesome but I'll have somethign to work on ;-)

Comment: sure I can do that!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$${_2F_1}(a,1,a+2k,-1)=\frac{\Gamma(0)\left(\Gamma(a+2k)\text{P}^{-1+a+2k,1-2k}_{-1}(3)\right)}{\Gamma(-1+a+2k)}$$

With $P_n^{(a,b)}(x)$ is the Jacobi polynomial!

Comment: +1 cool.. so two question: Isn't $\Gamma(0) = 1$? why do you write it? and 2) I'm no asking for the proof, but how did you "guess" this solution? Thanks anyhow! IT seems great ;-)

Comment: No it isnt, you've to find it in the context of the all function! I'm working for a long time on complex analysis and hypergeometric functions, this was one of the subjects I was working on.